# obj file in Rajawali library

Tags: android, vuforia, rajawali

I had tried rajawalivuforia. I want to add an obj file to render on my marker.
Here is my code:

```
LoaderOBJ objParser = new LoaderOBJ(mContext.getResources(), mTextureManager, R.raw.apple_obj);
        objParser.parse();
        mApple = objParser.getParsedObject();
        addChild(mApple);
```

The app crashed after I added in this code. Is there any wrong with this code?
Please help!
Thanks.

Comment: Can you please attach the log, what exact error you are getting?

Comment: Eclipse show no error for it. It cannot be run after I installed.

Comment: I know the problem. Is the obj format problem. when i use the obj from  other project it work find. When i use the obj file that i export from 3ds max, it cannot run. Same as for the md2 file. I have no idea how to get the file that can be support by it.